# How does 亡 's original meaning (cutting edge of knife) semantically appertain its senses of 1. escaped and 2. go away?

Tags: etymology

CUHK substantiates [Wiktionary's asseveration](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BA%A1#Glyph_origin)

> Ideogram (*[指事](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%8C%87%E4%BA%8B#Chinese)*): a line on [刀](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%88%80#Chinese) – [cutting edge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cutting_edge) of a [knife](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knife); the original form of [芒](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8A%92#Chinese) (*OC *maːŋ, *maŋ*, “edge of a knife”).

But I don't understand CUHK's 詳解 that I used Google to Translate.

> The word "death" in the Jiajin inscription starts with "sword", with a short picture indicating where the edge is. Fleeing, death, existence, etc. are false meanings.

> Oracle takes the guise of "nothing" in the guise of being or not, and "death (no) disaster". The inscriptions on Jinwen mean death, and the King of Zhongshan Fanghu: "Bang died and died." Also under the guise of "nothing", Zhongshan Wang Fanghu: "A husband who died (nothing) can save." It is also known as the "forget" of forgetting, and the father of the Diao family: "The virtues do not die (forget)", which is also used as a person's name.

1. How are "逃亡、死亡、有無等是假借之義"? Undeniably knives can cause, thus are related to, death.
2. But how does a knife's cutting edge semantically shift to signify fleeing? If you're dead, you can't escape or flee physically!

[image]

Axel Schuessler, *ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese*  (2007), p. 507.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does 亡 's original meaning (cutting edge of knife) semantically appertain its senses of 1. escaped and 2. go away?

**It doesn't.** The quote from CUHK states it plainly:

> 逃亡、死亡、有無等是假借之義。
>
> The meanings *to flee*, *death*, *have not*, etc. are [phonetic loans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters).

The earliest phonetic loan usage of 「亡」 is a meaning like *to lose* ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*maŋ/**), [cognate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate) with 「無」 (**/*ma/**, *without*), 「忘」 (**/*maŋ/**, "lose memory" > *forget*). The semantic extension of 「亡」 into *flee* ("lose ground") and *die* ("lose life") are tightly coupled with the meaning *to lose*, and more importantly, are traceable. Your

> Undeniably knives can cause, thus are related to, death.

is not a tight or direct relation at all, and most importantly, is not traceable in literature. Someone making this claim must demonstrate that 「亡」 is used to bridge the gap between *knife* and *death*, and the bridge must be a verb meaning *to kill*. Such a bridge doesn't exist.